# Might be a stupid question on derivatives of summations...

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

I am realizing at the moment that

$$\frac{d}{dx_i} (\sum _j x_j)^2 = \frac{d}{dx_i} (\sum_j x_j^2 + 2 \sum_{j < k} x_j x_k) = 2 x_i + 2 \sum_{j < k} x_k,$$
but this is not the same as:

$$\frac{d}{dx_i} (\sum_j x_j)^2 = 2 \sum_j x_j \cdot \frac{d}{dx_i} \sum_j x_j = 2 \sum_j x_j$$

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Notice that in the sum $\sum_{i\neq j}x_ix_j$, then term $x_ix_j$ appear two times, as $x_ix_j$ and $x_jx_i$, so the sum is equal to $2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j$

Comment: This is kind of funny. You differentiated with respect to $x_i$ but you also used $i$ to denote the index you're summing over. If you hadn't done that, you may have realized that the last term in the top right hand side is actually over $i \neq j$ (and not $i<j$). Then the two are the same.

Comment: Ok. I have changed it to reflect that, but I am still wondering why it doesn't match...

Comment: @DionelJaime I changed it but I still don't understand how it's over $i \neq j$ and not $i < j$. Can you explain? Thanks!

Comment: Try it was $x_1$. Get a feel for it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using $i$ as two different things, which is causing problems. First, we are using $i$ to label which $x$ we are taking the derivative with respect to, and we are using it to as the index of our summation. To see why this is a problem, let's see what happens if we get rid of the square. We have $\frac d {dx_i} \left(\sum x_i\right)$ it looks like this should be $\sum 1$, but we know this isn't the case. If you take the derivative of $\sum x_i$ with respect to any given $x_j$ you get 1. Taking this indexing into account, your first equation becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dx_i}\left(\sum x_j\right)^2 = \frac{d}{dx_i}\left(\sum x_j^2 + 2\sum_{j<k} x_jx_k\right) = 2x_i + 2\sum_{j< i} x_j + 2\sum_{i< k}x_k = 2\sum x_j
$$
On the other hand, the second equation becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dx_i}\left(\sum x_j\right)^2 = 2\sum x_j \cdot \frac{d}{dx_i}\sum x_j = 2\sum x_j \cdot 1 = 2\sum x_j
$$

As you can see, these are equal.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx_k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2
=\frac{d}{dx_k}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2+\frac{d}{dx_k}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne i}^n x_ix_j
=2x_k+\sum_{i=1,\\i\ne k}^nx_i+\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne k}^nx_j$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dx_k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2
=2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\left(\frac{d}{dx_k}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)
=2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\cdot1.$$

$$\begin{matrix}x_1^2&x_1x_2&x_1x_3\\x_2x_1&x_2^2&x_2x_3\\x_3x_1&x_3x_2&x_3^2\end{matrix}\to
\begin{matrix}2x_1&x_2&x_3\\x_2&0&0\\x_3&0&0\end{matrix}$$